# Oracle: materialized view fast refresh fails when column name begins with double quotes

Tags: oracle, performance, refresh

all!

Version: Oracle 12.2

Mat.view fast refresh fails when in WHERE clause
there is column , starting with double quotes and underscore, like that:
"_ID".
Do you know workaround, other than rename column in base tabl

Comment: I didn't get the point ? why are you referring the column in where within `"_ID" ` and why not  just `_ID` ?

Comment: try it yourself, please.  select _ID doesn't work, but select "_ID" works. Columns were named by "unknown" programmer, I can't rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rename column in base table; rename column in materialized view:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 _ID                                                VARCHAR2(20)
 SOME_COL                                           VARCHAR2(3)

SQL> create materialized view mv_test as
  2    select "_ID" as id,                      --> this
  3           some_col
  4  from test;

Materialized view created.

SQL> desc mv_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 VARCHAR2(20)
 SOME_COL                                           VARCHAR2(3)

SQL>
```

Comment: I did! Corresponding Column in matview named hst_id
But it doesn’t work…
This is how oracle refreshes
/*+ MV_REFRESH(INS) */
INSERT /*+ NOAPPEND*/ INTO
…
Select 
…
“MAS$2”.”_ID”
…
FROM <table with “_ID” column> AS OF SNAPSHOT(:B_SCN) “MAS$2”,
(SELECT … FROM  <table with “_ID” column> AS OF SNAPSHOT(:B_SCN) “MAS$”
 WHERE ROWID IN
(select chartorowid’() from “MLOG$_< on table with “_ID” column > “MAS$”
Where “mas$”.snaptime$$  > :B_ST0)
) AS OF SNAPSHOT(:B_SCN) “JV$”
WHERE 
…
AND “MAS$2”.”_ID” <> “JV$”.”_ID”

Answer (score 0):

I tried as you said and i have created a small demo as per my understanding from your question.

please find below observation,

```
--drop table test_mv;
create table test_mv("_ID" number primary key,NAME varchar2(100));

--data
insert into test_mv values (1,'first row');
insert into test_mv values (2,'second row');
commit;

--trying to select without ""
select *
  from test_mv
where _ID = 1;
--result 
--Error report -
--SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
--00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"

--trying to select with ""
select *
  from test_mv
where "_ID" = 1;
--result
_ID NAME                                                                                                
--- -----
1   first row

--mat view log
create materialized view log on test_mv;
--output: Materialized view log TEST_MV created.

--drop materialized view mv_test_mv;
--create materialized view giving "_id" in where clause as you described and `on commit`
create materialized view mv_test_mv 
refresh fast on commit
as
select *
  from test_mv
where "_ID" = 1;
--output: Materialized view MV_TEST_MV created.

--selecting from mat view
select * from mv_test_mv;

--output:
_id NAME                                                                                                
--- -----
1   first row

--update the base table record
update test_mv set name = 'modified first row' where "_ID" = 1;
commit;
--output
--1 row updated.
--Commit complete.

--selecting again from mat view to check if the changes propagated to the mat view or not
select * from mv_test_mv;

output:
_ID NAME                                                                                                
--- ------------------
1   modified first row
```

**It all worked fine even though I have a where clause with "_ID".**

*Is this what you are saying or something else which I didn't understand ?*

Comment: Your example is OK. But I don't know what's wrong in my case. Here a piece of Oracle internals(catched from v$session):`/*+ MV_REFRESH(INS) */ INSERT /*+ NOAPPEND*/ INTO … Select … “MAS$2”.”_ID” … FROM <table with “_ID” column> AS OF SNAPSHOT(:B_SCN) “MAS$2”, (SELECT … FROM <table with “_ID” column> AS OF SNAPSHOT(:B_SCN) “MAS$” WHERE ROWID IN (select chartorowid’() from “MLOG$_< on table with “_ID” column > “MAS$” Where “mas$”.snaptime$$ > :B_ST0) ) AS OF SNAPSHOT(:B_SCN) “JV$” WHERE … AND “MAS$2”.”_ID” <> “JV$”.”_ID” `

Comment: sorry for bad formatting, newline is not allowed in mini-comments...